# Material UI animation isn't easing with webkit scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to make the webkit scrollbar ease in and out by using css animations in Material UI's sx property. The animation makes the scrollbar appear and disappear, but it happens instantly instead of easing in and out.

Defining the keyframes in the sx property and outside of it behaved identically. Below is my code.

```
const fadeIn = keyframes`
  0% {
    --var1: inherit;
  }
  100% {
    --var1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  }
`;

const fadeOut = keyframes`
  0% {
    --var1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  }
  100% {
    --var1: inherit;
  }
`;



const ShowsRow = ({ children, genre }) => {
  return (
    <Paper
      sx={{
        border: { border },
        maxHeight: "min(30%, 400px)",
        padding: "min(1%, 20px) 0",
        borderRadius: "0",
        transition: "background-color 0.3s ease-in-out",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        "@property --var1": {
          syntax: "<color>",
          inherits: true,
          initialValue: "inherit",
        },
        animation: `${fadeOut} 0.3s ease-in-out forwards`,
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)", // Change the background color on hover
          animation: `${fadeIn} 0.3s ease-in-out forwards`,
        },
      }}
      elevation={2}
    >
      <Typography
        variant="h5"
        sx={{ fontWeight: "bold", padding: "0 0 min(1%, 20px) min(1%, 20px)" }}
      >
        {genre}
      </Typography>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "flex-start",
          border: { border },
          gap: "min(3%, 20px)",
          width: "100%",
          overflowX: "scroll",
          overflowY: "hidden",
          padding: "0 min(1%, 20px)",
          "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
            height: "0.8em",
            background: "transparent",
          },
          "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
            background: "var(--var1)",
            borderRadius: "1em",
          },
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

can you just try this code. Mostly it will fix your issue

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  showsRow: {
    border: theme.border,
    maxHeight: 'min(30%, 400px)',
    padding: 'min(1%, 20px) 0',
    borderRadius: '0',
    transition: 'background-color 0.3s ease-in-out',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)',
    },
  },
  fadeIn: {
    animation: '$fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out forwards',
  },
  fadeOut: {
    animation: '$fadeOut 0.3s ease-in-out forwards',
  },
  '@keyframes fadeIn': {
    '0%': {
      '--var1': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)',
    },
    '100%': {
      '--var1': 'inherit',
    },
  },
  '@keyframes fadeOut': {
    '0%': {
      '--var1': 'inherit',
    },
    '100%': {
      '--var1': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)',
    },
  },
}));

const ShowsRow = ({ children, genre }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    // Add the fadeIn class when hovering
    // This will trigger the animation defined in CSS
    const element = document.getElementById('scrollbox');
    element.classList.add(classes.fadeIn);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    // Add the fadeOut class when not hovering
    // This will trigger the animation defined in CSS
    const element = document.getElementById('scrollbox');
    element.classList.add(classes.fadeOut);
  };

  return (
    <Paper
      className={classes.showsRow}
      elevation={2}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      <Typography
        variant="h5"
        sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold', padding: '0 0 min(1%, 20px) min(1%, 20px)' }}
      >
        {genre}
      </Typography>
      <Box
        id="scrollbox"
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'flex-start',
          border: '1px solid #e0e0e0',
          gap: 'min(3%, 20px)',
          width: '100%',
          overflowX: 'scroll',
          overflowY: 'hidden',
          padding: '0 min(1%, 20px)',
          '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
            height: '0.8em',
            background: 'transparent',
          },
          '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
            background: 'var(--var1)',
            borderRadius: '1em',
          },
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default ShowsRow;
```